# How does javascript know it has reached the end of __proto__ lookup chain

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am reading about the **proto** chain in javascript . I am trying to understand how javascript would know it has reached the end of `__proto__` chain. Which will actually be inside the object pointed to by `Object.prototype` . So far I have grasped the following please correct me if I am wrong.

Every constructor function has a property called `prototype` and it also has a property called `__proto__` by default `__proto__` points to `Object.prototype`. However once an instance of an object is created using new, The `__proto__` property of that instance is assigned a new value which is `ConstructorName.prototype`. Now during use when a property is not found in the local scope of the object. Javascript looks inside the object pointed to by `__proto__` if the object is not found in there it then looks inside the object pointed to by the `__proto__` of that object and the process continues. My question is now if the process continues it seems like eventually it will end up inside the object pointed to by `Object.prototype.` Does this `Object.prototype` have a `__proto__` ?? I looked inside chrome and it seems it doesnt however it has getters and setters of proto so I am not sure about.that. I would like to know how this lookup ends.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the following expressions are true:

```js
console.log(Object.prototype.__proto__ === null);
console.log(Object.prototype.constructor === Object);
```

This means that the prototype chain via `__proto__` ends when its value becomes `null`.

However, the constructor of `Object.prototype` is again `Object`, so that really is an endless loop. That, of course, is just the way it is implemented and does not mean that `Object.prototype` was created by `new Object()`.

#### Prototype-less objects

You can also create an object which does not have a `__proto__`. These two expressions are true:

```js
console.log(Object.create(null).__proto__ === undefined);
console.log(Object.create(null).constructor === undefined);
```

#### `__proto__`: both standardised and deprecated

A nice [article on `__proto__`](http://www.2ality.com/2015/09/proto-es6.html) mentions:

> Because `__proto__` was so widely supported, it was decided that its behavior should be standardized for ECMAScript 6. However, due to its problematic nature, it was added as a deprecated feature.

#### `Object.getPrototypeOf()`

For getting information about an object's prototype it is advised to use `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` instead of `obj.__proto__`:

```js
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf({}) === Object.prototype);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype) === null);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.create(null)) === null);
```